# Node / Electron: Cannot find module '"c:/Program'

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-modules

While running an Electron application using the script `npm run debug`, the VSCode terminal throws up the error: `Cannot find module '"c:/Program'`

It does not even mention the full directory name `Program Files` and the rest of the path.

The full error stack trace is:

```
Error: Cannot find module '"c:/Program'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:510:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:640:17)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:809:12)
    at preloadModules (internal/bootstrap/node.js:591:7)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:272:9)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:759:3)
```

What is wrong in my environment and how can I fix it?
My OS is Windows 10 and I have nvm installed.

The log file mentions the path as `C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\scoop\\apps\\nvm\\current\\nodejs\\nodejs\\node.exe`

I suspect it to be some issue with PATH variable or with nvm.

EDIT 1:

After modifying the PATH and inserting quotes around all paths having spaces, the npm run debug started working when run from the integrated terminal. But when I run the same using the VSCode Run and Debug tab, then I still get the same error.

My nvm path is: `C:\Users\MyUserName\scoop\persist\nvm`

I guess I installed nvm using scoop long ago.

My `debug` script is:

'npm run dotenv && electron --inspect=5858 ./out/src/main.js'

If I create a separate script with the command `npm run dotenv` and run it from the UI using the Run and Debug tab, then I am not getting any error.

So I guess the error is in running the electron part of the command.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you have a path string with spaces and when node sees that it ignores the part of the directory name after the space.

Try using double quotes when you define the path and use double backlashes when defining the path string

Comment: But I did not manually edit the PATH variable. The PATH variable was updated by all the various applications / libraries which I installed, and it is quite common for Windows to have PATH without the quotes. Do all Windows users get this error and then manually change the PATH to surround all paths having spaces with quotes? In my system, there are around 15-20 occurences of C:\Program Files without the quotes.

Comment: Anyhow, after editing the PATH and inserting quotes around all paths having spaces, the `npm run debug` started working. But when I run the same using the VSCode Run and Debug tab, then I still get the same error.

Comment: From where does the VSCode Run and Debug read the PATH?

Comment: I am using the dotenv library, like this: r`equire('dotenv').config();` and my debug script calls this: `npm run dotenv && electron --inspect=5858 ./out/src/main.js`